# group and filter large array in array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array of array like this

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 2
                [3] => 3
                [4] => 4
                [5] => 5
                [6] => 6
                [7] => 7
                [8] => 8
                [9] => 9
                [10] => 10
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 4
                [4] => 5
                [5] => 6
                [6] => 7
                [7] => 8
                [8] => 9
                [9] => 10
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 4
                [3] => 5
                [4] => 6
                [5] => 7
                [6] => 8
                [7] => 9
                [8] => 10
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 5
                [3] => 6
                [4] => 7
                [5] => 8
                [6] => 9
                [7] => 10
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 6
                [3] => 7
                [4] => 8
                [5] => 9
                [6] => 10
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
                [1] => 6
                [2] => 7
                [3] => 8
                [4] => 9
                [5] => 10
            )

        [50] => Array
            (
                [0] => 125
                [1] => 126
                [2] => 127
                [3] => 128
                [4] => 129
                [5] => 130
                [6] => 131
                [7] => 132
                [8] => 133
                [9] => 134
                [10] => 135
            )

        [51] => Array
            (
                [0] => 126
                [1] => 127
                [2] => 128
                [3] => 129
                [4] => 130
                [5] => 131
                [6] => 132
                [7] => 133
                [8] => 134
                [9] => 135
            )

        [52] => Array
            (
                [0] => 127
                [1] => 128
                [2] => 129
                [3] => 130
                [4] => 131
                [5] => 132
                [6] => 133
                [7] => 134
                [8] => 135
            )

        [53] => Array
            (
                [0] => 128
                [1] => 129
                [2] => 130
                [3] => 131
                [4] => 132
                [5] => 133
                [6] => 134
                [7] => 135
            )
    )
```

The complete list I uploaded here;

[complete array element list](http://nilzoom.com/a/sample.php)

I have to group these values as they biggest parent.
For example the above code will result:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 2
                [3] => 3
                [4] => 4
                [5] => 5
                [6] => 6
                [7] => 7
                [8] => 8
                [9] => 9
                [10] => 10
            )

        [50] => Array
            (
                [0] => 125
                [1] => 126
                [2] => 127
                [3] => 128
                [4] => 129
                [5] => 130
                [6] => 131
                [7] => 132
                [8] => 133
                [9] => 134
                [10] => 135
            )
    )
```

First, I can sort these by the values count and then grab the largest but this is out put of my other script and can be very different;

For example,
This output have 113 element with two group but maybe other have 8 group and 80 element
so I need a solution to filter all repeated value and just return the biggest element in each value groups.

Comment: please explain 'group these values as they biggest parent'

Comment: Your sample source array is pre-ordered (values from small to large, value count from large to small). Is this guaranteed?

Comment: @arilia : if you see the link i submitted in the body group mean same values after each other

Comment: @Passerby : yes! values every time are sorted small to large and count will be large to small! i need larger count in each group!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source array is **always** pre-ordered as:

1. every sub-array is ordered from smaller value to larger value;
2. sub-arrays with the same largest value are ordered in a superset - subset order (i.e. `[0,1,2],[1,2]`, not `[1,2],[0,1,2]`, and not `[0,1,3,4],[1,2,4]`)

Then this can be simply done by a `foreach`:

```
function reduce_array(array $source)
{
    $picked_mark=array();
    $result=array();
    foreach ($source as $key=>$subarray)
    {
        if (in_array(end($subarray),$picked_mark)) continue;
        $result[$key]=$subarray;
        $picked_mark[]=end($subarray);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/q8URK)